# How do I set up m2eclipse to see the archetypes in repo1.maven.org?

Tags: configuration, maven-2, repository, archetypes

As in the title. I can't find any archetype catalogues for repo1.maven.org

For example, I want to use spring-ws-archetype. How do I set things up so I can see it in my options setting up a new Maven Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent versions of the plugin have the 'Nexus Indexer' installed by default, which provides access to the archetypes from repo1.maven.org.

[Preferences page http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/1186/archetypepreferences.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/1186/archetypepreferences.png)
[Archetype selection http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/4508/archetypeselection.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/4508/archetypeselection.png)